# Calculating rate of a given field value (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I have a simple table with EventDate and Attended where Attended contains 1 of 5 values (Attended, Canceled, Did Not Attend, Other, Unknown). I need a query that returns the RATE of the Unknowns. I don't care about the rates of the other values.

I know I can use the where clause to return the number of records where the value of Attended is 'Unknown', but I need to ultimately arrive at the percentage of the total, preferably in one query.

This query gets the total of the Unknowns, but where do I go from here to get JUST the percentage of Unknowns?

```
SELECT Count(Attended) As TotalCount
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE (Attended = 'Unknown')
AND Month(EventDate) = 1
AND Year(EventDate) = 2016
GROUP BY Attended
```

Hint: There are 11300 total rows, and 2212 where the value is Unknown. I want a query that returns .195 (which is 2212 / 11300 = 19.5%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional `COUNT()`

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN Attended = 'Unknown' THEN 1 END ) * 100.0 
           /
       COUNT(*) As UnknowRate
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE Month(EventDate) = 1
  AND Year(EventDate) = 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "conditional count" with a `CASE` statement, like this:

```
select 
    count(*) as TotalCount,
    sum(case when Attended = 'Unknown' then 1 else 0 end) as AttendedUnknownCount,
    cast(sum(case when Attended = 'Unknown' then 1 else 0 end) as float)
    / cast(count(*) as float) as PctAttendedUnknown
from MyTable
Where Month(EventDate) = 1 and Year(EventDate) = 2016
```

Note that since you are considering all rows for the total (not just the "Unknown" ones), you don't have to do a `group by`